# Select * where association is empty in SQL?

Tags: mysql

So I'm a bit lost in SQL and especially in the right syntax to use.

To be quick : These are my tables

We have products :

```
+------------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| Field                  | Type             | Null | Key | Default             | Extra          |
+------------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| id                     | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL                | auto_increment |
| slug                   | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| title                  | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| resume                 | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| country_id             | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| city_id                | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
+------------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
```

And we have cities :

```
+------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| Field            | Type             | Null | Key | Default             | Extra          |
+------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| id               | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL                | auto_increment |
| country_id       | int(11)          | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| name             | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
+------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
```

What I want to find is **which cities does not have products**.

So basically I tried something like this :

> SELECT name 
>   FROM cities 
>   WHERE COUNT (SELECT * FROM cities INNER JOIN
>   products ON products.city_id = cities.id) = 0;

I think I have a misunderstanding of how `COUNT` works, can someone help on this one?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do it with `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT name 
FROM cities AS c
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM products AS p
                  WHERE p.city_id = c.id)
```

The above query returns the names of all cities not being linked to a product.

Comment: Ok nice one can I just have a bit of highlighting on the `SELECT 1` pls?

Comment: @Baldráni `NOT EXISTS` just checks for the existence of at least one record in `products` table being related to a record of `cities` table. It doesn't need any fields returned by the `SELECT` clause of the subquery to operate. Hence, it suffices to just do a `SELECT 1`.

Comment: Ok I get it Thank you very much !

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following query:

```
SELECT name
FROM cities
WHERE id NOT IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT city_id FROM products
)
```